# ValidationException: One of the required keys was not given a value (Localstack, AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

I am new to AWS and Localstack.

I have written a test on a model which adds item to dynamoDB table using localstack.
Before, I tested it was working fine.
Then after I have renamed its PrimaryKey field from 'Etag' to 'Hash' from code.
And run test again and it gives above error which I have mentioned in the title.

I think I need to recreate the table in local environment.
Because there is already same table with 'Etag' field and I am passing 'Hash'.

But, I don't know the command to list and remove dynamoDB tables from local environment using localstack.

What should I do?

Help me guys...

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't paste code and error messages as screenshots.

Comment: @Marcin, I have removed screenshots from the question.
I have added it just to explain the situation.
But, It's okay.

Comment: You can paste code as code blocks.

Comment: okay, I will keep it in mind.
Do you know the commands? 
If you know please help me.

Comment: How to make code blocks is shown [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).